# CSS/JS Files aren't being included in HTML with Grunt JS

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, yeoman

Currently trying to process a build and I've gotten the source files to be included into the dist directory. But the files aren't being included into the index.html files within my yeoman webapp.

Just need to know what else I need to do to have these files included within the index.html build.

Here's my Gruntfile.js

```
// Generated on 2014-10-17 using
// generator-webapp 0.5.0
'use strict';

// # Globbing
// for performance reasons we're only matching one level down:
// 'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
// If you want to recursively match all subfolders, use:
// 'test/spec/**/*.js'

module.exports = function (grunt) {

  // Time how long tasks take. Can help when optimizing build times
  require('time-grunt')(grunt);

  // Load grunt tasks automatically
  require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

  // Configurable paths
  var config = {
    app: 'app',
    dist: 'dist'
  };

  // Define the configuration for all the tasks
  grunt.initConfig({

    // Project settings
    config: config,

    // Watches files for changes and runs tasks based on the changed files
    watch: {
      bower: {
        files: ['bower.json'],
        tasks: ['wiredep']
      },
      js: {
        files: ['<%= config.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'],
        tasks: ['jshint'],
        options: {
          livereload: true
        }
      },
      jstest: {
        files: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js'],
        tasks: ['test:watch']
      },
      gruntfile: {
        files: ['Gruntfile.js']
      },
      sass: {
        files: ['<%= config.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
        tasks: ['sass:server', 'autoprefixer']
      },
      styles: {
        files: ['<%= config.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
        tasks: ['newer:copy:styles', 'autoprefixer']
      },
      livereload: {
        options: {
          livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
        },
        files: [
          '<%= config.app %>/{,*/}*.html',
          '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
          '<%= config.app %>/images/{,*/}*'
        ]
      }
    },

    // The actual grunt server settings
    connect: {
      options: {
        port: 9000,
        open: true,
        livereload: 35729,
        // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside
        hostname: 'localhost'
      },
      livereload: {
        options: {
          middleware: function(connect) {
            return [
              connect.static('.tmp'),
              connect().use('/bower_components', connect.static('./bower_components')),
              connect.static(config.app)
            ];
          }
        }
      },
      test: {
        options: {
          open: false,
          port: 9001,
          middleware: function(connect) {
            return [
              connect.static('.tmp'),
              connect.static('test'),
              connect().use('/bower_components', connect.static('./bower_components')),
              connect.static(config.app)
            ];
          }
        }
      },
      dist: {
        options: {
          base: '<%= config.dist %>',
          livereload: false
        }
      }
    },

    // Empties folders to start fresh
    clean: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          dot: true,
          src: [
            '.tmp',
            '<%= config.dist %>/*',
            '!<%= config.dist %>/.git*'
          ]
        }]
      },
      server: '.tmp'
    },

    // Make sure code styles are up to par and there are no obvious mistakes
    jshint: {
      options: {
        jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
        reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
      },
      all: [
        'Gruntfile.js',
        '<%= config.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
        '!<%= config.app %>/scripts/vendor/*',
        'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
      ]
    },

    // Mocha testing framework configuration options
    mocha: {
      all: {
        options: {
          run: true,
          urls: ['http://<%= connect.test.options.hostname %>:<%= connect.test.options.port %>/index.html']
        }
      }
    },

    // Compiles Sass to CSS and generates necessary files if requested
    sass: {
      options: {
        sourcemap: false,
        loadPath: 'bower_components'
      },
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= config.app %>/styles',
          src: ['*.{scss,sass}'],
          dest: '.tmp/styles',
          ext: '.css'
        }]
      },
      server: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= config.app %>/styles',
          src: ['*.{scss,sass}'],
          dest: '.tmp/styles',
          ext: '.css'
        }]
      }
    },

    // Add vendor prefixed styles
    autoprefixer: {
      options: {
        browsers: ['> 1%', 'last 2 versions', 'Firefox ESR', 'Opera 12.1']
      },
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
          src: '{,*/}*.css',
          dest: '.tmp/styles/'
        }]
      }
    },

    // Automatically inject Bower components into the HTML file
    wiredep: {
      app: {
        ignorePath: /^\/|\.\.\//,
        src: ['<%= config.app %>/index.html']
      },
      sass: {
        src: ['<%= config.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
        ignorePath: /(\.\.\/){1,2}bower_components\//
      }
    },

    // Renames files for browser caching purposes
    rev: {
      dist: {
        files: {
          src: [
            '<%= config.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
            '<%= config.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
            '<%= config.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.*',
            '<%= config.dist %>/styles/fonts/{,*/}*.*',
            '<%= config.dist %>/*.{ico,png}'
          ]
        }
      }
    },

    // Reads HTML for usemin blocks to enable smart builds that automatically
    // concat, minify and revision files. Creates configurations in memory so
    // additional tasks can operate on them
    useminPrepare: {
      options: {
        dest: '<%= config.dist %>'
      },
      html: '<%= config.app %>/index.html'
    },

    // Performs rewrites based on rev and the useminPrepare configuration
    usemin: {
      options: {
        assetsDirs: ['<%= config.dist %>', '<%= config.dist %>/images']
      },
      html: ['<%= config.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
      css: ['<%= config.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css']
    },

    // The following *-min tasks produce minified files in the dist folder
    imagemin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= config.app %>/images',
          src: '{,*/}*.{gif,jpeg,jpg,png}',
          dest: '<%= config.dist %>/images'
        }]
      }
    },

    svgmin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= config.app %>/images',
          src: '{,*/}*.svg',
          dest: '<%= config.dist %>/images'
        }]
      }
    },

    htmlmin: {
      dist: {
        options: {
          collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
          collapseWhitespace: false,
          conservativeCollapse: true,
          removeAttributeQuotes: false,
          removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
          removeEmptyAttributes: false,
          removeOptionalTags: false,
          removeRedundantAttributes: false,
          useShortDoctype: true
        },
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= config.dist %>',
          src: '{,*/}*.html',
          dest: '<%= config.dist %>'
        }]
      }
    },

    // By default, your `index.html`'s <!-- Usemin block --> will take care
    // of minification. These next options are pre-configured if you do not
    // wish to use the Usemin blocks.
    // cssmin: {
    //   dist: {
    //     files: {
    //       '<%= config.dist %>/styles/main.css': [
    //         '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
    //         '<%= config.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'
    //       ]
    //     }
    //   }
    // },
    // uglify: {
    //   dist: {
    //     files: {
    //       '<%= config.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js': [
    //         '<%= config.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js'
    //       ]
    //     }
    //   }
    // },
    // concat: {
    //   dist: {}
    // },

    // Copies remaining files to places other tasks can use
    copy: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          dot: true,
          cwd: '<%= config.app %>',
          dest: '<%= config.dist %>',
          src: [
            '*.{ico,png,txt}',
            'images/{,*/}*.webp',
            '{,*/}*.html',
            'fonts/{,*/}*.*',
            'styles/fonts/{,*/}*.*',
            'styles/vendor/{,*/}*.*',
            'scripts/vendor/{,*/}*.*'
          ]
        }, {
          src: 'node_modules/apache-server-configs/dist/.htaccess',
          dest: '<%= config.dist %>/.htaccess'
        }]
      },
      styles: {
        expand: true,
        dot: true,
        cwd: '<%= config.app %>/styles',
        dest: '.tmp/styles/',
        src: '{,*/}*.css'
      }
    },

    // Generates a custom Modernizr build that includes only the tests you
    // reference in your app
    modernizr: {
      dist: {
        devFile: 'bower_components/modernizr/modernizr.js',
        outputFile: '<%= config.dist %>/scripts/vendor/modernizr.js',
        files: {
          src: [
            '<%= config.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
            '<%= config.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
            '!<%= config.dist %>/scripts/vendor/*'
          ]
        },
        uglify: true
      }
    },

    // Run some tasks in parallel to speed up build process
    concurrent: {
      server: [
        'sass:server',
        'copy:styles'
      ],
      test: [
        'copy:styles'
      ],
      dist: [
        'sass',
        'copy:styles',
        'imagemin',
        'svgmin'
      ]
    }
  });


  grunt.registerTask('serve', 'start the server and preview your app, --allow-remote for remote access', function (target) {
    if (grunt.option('allow-remote')) {
      grunt.config.set('connect.options.hostname', '0.0.0.0');
    }
    if (target === 'dist') {
      return grunt.task.run(['build', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
    }

    grunt.task.run([
      'clean:server',
      'wiredep',
      'concurrent:server',
      'autoprefixer',
      'connect:livereload',
      'watch'
    ]);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('server', function (target) {
    grunt.log.warn('The `server` task has been deprecated. Use `grunt serve` to start a server.');
    grunt.task.run([target ? ('serve:' + target) : 'serve']);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('test', function (target) {
    if (target !== 'watch') {
      grunt.task.run([
        'clean:server',
        'concurrent:test',
        'autoprefixer'
      ]);
    }

    grunt.task.run([
      'connect:test',
      'mocha'
    ]);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean:dist',
    'wiredep',
    'useminPrepare',
    'concurrent:dist',
    'autoprefixer',
    'concat',
    'cssmin',
    'uglify',
    'copy:dist',
    'modernizr',
    'rev',
    'usemin',
    'htmlmin'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'newer:jshint',
    'test',
    'build'
  ]);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.  You have to provide a reference for wiredep part of the process, it wires the different bits of your web site together.

If you look at the index.html file created when you fist ran yeoman, you should seem some references to included files in the <-- comments.  You need to duplicate these, with the files that you want to include between them.

The starting references is

`<!--build:js({app,.tmp}) blah blah`  and the end references is `<!-- endbuild -->`

Comment: See https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-usemin for a better source of information.